# How to prevent double rendering when importing my components?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a Todo List app saving data in localstorage but when i reaload the page, my components renders twice creating empty data and replacing by the previous tasks saved in localstorage.

This is my main file: `main.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';

import './scss/styles.scss';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Also main.jsx's child: `App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ToDo from './Components/ToDo';

const App = () => (
  <div className="container-fluid col-md-5 mx-auto" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <h1 className="text-center fw-bold">
      To do app
    </h1>
    <ToDo />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

This is App.jsx's child: `ToDo.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faListCheck, faCirclePlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import SimpleToast from './Alerts/SimpleToast';
import Items from './Items';

const ToDo = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasks');
    if (storedTasks) {
      setTasks(JSON.parse(storedTasks));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  const handleAddTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (newTask.trim() === '') {
      SimpleToast.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Enter a task first',
      });
      return;
    }
    setTasks([...tasks, { id: Date.now(), text: newTask, completed: false }]);
    setNewTask('');
  };
  const handleDeleteTask = (taskId) => {
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddTask}>
        <div className="form-floating position-relative">
          <input
            id="new-task"
            type="text"
            className="form-control shadow-lg"
            placeholder="Enter a new task"
            value={newTask}
            onChange={(e) => setNewTask(e.target.value)}
          />
          <label htmlFor="new-task">
            Enter a new task
            {' '}
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faListCheck} />
          </label>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              type="submit"
              className="position-absolute translate-middle fs-3"
              icon={faCirclePlus}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Items tasks={tasks} handleDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ToDo;
```

also the items components:

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

const Items = ({ tasks, handleDeleteTask }) => (
  <ul className="list-group-flush bg-white rounded shadow-lg my-3 p-3">
    {tasks.length === 0 ? <li className="text-center list-group-item"> No tasks</li> : tasks.map((task) => (
      <Item key={task.id} task={task.text} handleDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask} idTask={task.id} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

export default Items;
```

and the item component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { faPen, faTrash, faFloppyDisk } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

const Item = ({ task, handleDeleteTask, idTask }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setText(task);
  }, [task]);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    if (!isEdit) {
      setIsEdit(true);
      return;
    }
    setIsEdit(false);
  };

  const handleCheckTask = () => {
    if (!isSelected) {
      setIsSelected(true);
      return;
    }
    setIsSelected(false);
  };

  return (
    <li className="row border rounded shadow-md p-1 my-2">
      <div className="col-1 p-0 text-center align-middle">
        <input className="form-check-input align-middle" type="checkbox" onChange={() => handleCheckTask()} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-9 p-0">
        <input className={`form-control border-0 text-dark ${isSelected ? 'text-decoration-line-through' : 'text-decoration-none'}`} value={text} type="text" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} disabled={!isEdit} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-1 p-0">
        <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={() => handleEdit()}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-danger" icon={!isEdit ? faPen : faFloppyDisk} />
        </button>

      </div>
      <div className="col-1 p-0">
        <button type="button" className="btn">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-danger" icon={faTrash} onClick={() => handleDeleteTask(idTask)} />
        </button>

      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

I have tried logging inside `Todo.jsx` first useEffect `console.log(storedTasks)` and when I reload i can see the previous tasks in console but after that a new empty array that i think is replacing the first array.

[image: logging storedTasks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overwriting tasks with the default value every time you load. A quick an easy solution is if you change your second useEffect to run only on a valid task like for instance if there is a value in tasks or if tasks is defined.

you will need to define your tasks as undefined

```js
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(undefined);
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
   // here we check if it's valid before storing it
    if(tasks){
      localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    }
  }, [tasks]);
```

### rendering

when rendering we use the logical or `||` to render 0 tasks when task is undefined

```html
<Items tasks={tasks || []} handleDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask} />
```

### summary code

```js
const ToDo = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(undefined);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasks');
    if (storedTasks) {
      console.log(storedTasks, " set");
      setTasks(JSON.parse(storedTasks));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(tasks != undefined){
      localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    }
  }, [tasks]);

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <Items tasks={tasks || []} handleDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: Watch out for bugs if you decide to clear the tasks by doing `setTasks([])`, what you are doing here seems to me like a work-around

Comment: good call. updated with a more complete solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this use `storedTasks.length` instead of `storedTask` as `Boolean` of empty array is `true`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasks');
    if (storedTasks.length) {
      setTasks(JSON.parse(storedTasks));
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Just tried but it's not working. This is the first time I get an error like this idk if it's because I am using vite (first time using vite too)

Answer (score 0):

I think The following

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);
```

might fire the first time as well as the useEffect above it, and since setTasks might not have taken effect when this code is executed, tasks would be `[]`.

I suggest doing `localStorage.setItem` directly where you are changing state like in `handleAddTask`. Add something like

```
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify([...tasks, { id: Date.now(), text: newTask, completed: false }]));
```

Note that I did not use `tasks` since setTasks might not have taken effect by the time the line is executed.

Comment: This might work for appending new tasks but isn't very useful for editing or removing tasks

Comment: Watch out for the concept behind this, the set of a `useState` does not necessarly take effect immediately like setting a variable in js. Understanding this could save you a lot of pain down the track.